# Inputs are lost when I load a saved model in Keras with a custom loss that takes multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

tf.**version**
'1.12.0'

I have a custom loss function that takes multiple inputs. It works fine except when I try to save and load the model. Here's a simple example that show how inputs are lost. Please have a look.

```
x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,), name='input')
y_true = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,), name='y_true' )
y_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
other_data = tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,), name='other_data' )
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[x, y_true, other_data],  outputs=y_pred)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_true -y_pred,2)) + tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_pred,other_data))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, beta_2=0.99), loss=custom_loss)

data = np.random.rand(5,5)
model.fit([data, data, data], data)

model.save('tmp.h5')
print(model.input_names)
model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('tmp.h5', custom_objects={'custom_loss':custom_loss})
print(model1.input_names)

model1.fit([data, data, data], data)
```

> Epoch 1/1 5/5 [==============================] - 0s 42ms/step - loss:
>   9.4392
>
> ['input', 'y_true', 'other_data'] **<--------------This is fine**
>
> ['input'] **<----------- What happend here?**
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 21, in 
>       model1.fit([data, data, data], data)
>
> File
>   "C:\src\Anaconda3\envs\deepema\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1536, in fit
>       validation_split=validation_split)
>
> File
>   "C:\src\Anaconda3\envs\deepema\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 992, in _standardize_user_data
>       class_weight, batch_size)
>
> File
>   "C:\src\Anaconda3\envs\deepema\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 1117, in _standardize_weights
>       exception_prefix='input')
>
> File
>   "C:\src\Anaconda3\envs\deepema\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py",
>   line 293, in standardize_input_data
>       str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
>
> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 3
>   arrays: [array([[0.12768201, 0.06106967, 0.99779087, 0.50767692,
>   0.21839594],
>          [0.82444334, 0.1367274 , 0.14495117, 0.32396153, 0.24457874],
>          [0.29870316, 0.40644681, 0.69308081, 0.30091417, 0.776...

Comment: I’ve implemented a workaround were I recreate the model and compile it in my code instead of save and load model config. Then I set weights and optimize weights similar to how it’s implemented in load_model and model.save.